# C++ Game Library/ Engine like LWJGL in Java

Tags: java, c++, game-engine

I have been developing java games in lwjgl for quite a bit and now I want to switch to C++ for a new experience in game programming.

I read through quiet a lot of C++ Game engine/ libraries like SDL, SFML etc but I am really looking forward to something like LWJGL, where the code is similar to OpenGL native and supports OpenGL3 & above.

So is there a engine/ library like that? Or shall I just stick to Native OpenGL, I am really new to C++ Game development. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDL, SFML and Allegro all support using OpenGL directly so they're kind of like LWJGL in that regard. SFML and SDL 2 let you set the OpenGL version (Allegro only lets you use OpenGL 3.0 or no version specified at the moment). Of these, Allegro has the best documentation atm, SDL 2 the worst (SDL2 still isn't quite stable). SFMLs documentation is ok.

If you would tell us what exactly you're looking for you might get a more detailed answer.

**Update**: SDL2's documentation is quite usable by now, it's definitely not a reason not to use SDL2 anymore. Also, SDL2 seems to be stable.